# Ambiguous compilation in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have two header files, say h1 and h2, in both I've use `uint8_t`, in h1 I used `uint8_t` without `#include <stdint.h>` it compiled successfully, but for same in h2 the compiler gives error : uint8_t doesnot name a type; #include "ing" `stdint.h` results in a successful compilation.

Can somebody please explain this ambiguous compiler behavior. I am using CodeBlocks 16.01

h1:

```
//there is no error even if I don't include <stdint.h> and use uint8_t 
#ifndef AES_ENCRYPTION_H
#define AES_ENCRYPTION_H

class AES_Encryption
{

private:

    static const uint8_t S_BOX[256];
    static const uint8_t R_CON[11];

    uint8_t state[4][4];
    unsigned short int encryptionMode;
    unsigned short int Nr;
    unsigned short int Nk;

public:

    AES_Encryption(unsigned short int);

    static uint8_t get_SBOX_value(uint8_t);

    static uint8_t HEX01xARG(uint8_t);

    static uint8_t HEX02xARG(uint8_t);

    static uint8_t HEX03xARG(uint8_t);

    void populateState(uint8_t*);

    void transferCipherText(uint8_t*);

    void subBytes();

    void shiftRows();

    void mixColumns();

    void keyExpansion(const uint8_t*, uint8_t*);/*seperate thread*/

    void addRoundKey(uint8_t*, int);


   };


   #endif // AES_ENCRYPTION_H
```

h2:

```
#ifndef AES_DECRYPTION_H
#define AES_DECRYPTION_H


class AES_Decryption
{
public:
    AES_Decryption();
    uint8_t x; //error in this line : uint8_t doesnot name a type; this resolves on including <stdint.h>

protected:

private:
};

#endif
```

Comment: may be h1 is including some other header which in turn defines uint8_t?

Comment: Please post your code, I'm not a magician.

Comment: @setia, h1 doesn't include any other headers

Comment: But what includes h1, and what does it include before it?

Comment: I just tried both of the headers with g++ 8.1.0 on Linux, and I get an error for both of them. I also get an error with clang 6.0.0. Can you post the source file you are including these headers in? I suspect that a header being included before these headers is to blame.

Comment: @john01dav you should not compile headers on their own. You compile a .cpp file that does `#include "file.h"`

Comment: @M.M That is exactly what I did. Specifically, I created a cpp file with nothing but a #include directive in it, and then used `g++ -c source.cpp -o source.o`.

Comment: @M.M Obviously, because OP is getting errors. That means *something* is different. See my answer for what I think it is.

Comment: @john01dav the .cpp file for h1 includes `"h1.h"` and  `<algorithm.h>` for `std::swap()`. No other headers are there.

Comment: @Nilesh It is incredibly common for the headers that are being included to include their own headers. It is possible, although unlikely given the header that you are using, that stdint.h is included in this way. I recommend removing the algorithm.h include and commenting out any code that requires it to see if the error appears. If it does, then it confirms that algorithm.h is including stdint.h indirectly.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, when you include a header, it is equivalent to simply copy/pasting the header's source into the file where it is included.

For example, consider the following files:

somefunction.h:

```
int some_function();
```

somefunction.cpp:

```
#include "somefunction.h"

void some_function(){ return 1+1; }
```

When this is compiled, one of the first things the compiler (or, more specifically, the preprocessor) will do is translate somefunction.cpp into the following:

```
int some_function();

void some_function{ return 1+1; }
```

As you can see, the contents of somefunction.h were embedded into somefunction.cpp.

Now, to tie this back to your question, I suspect that where you are including  h1.h it looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "h1.h"
```

Because the contents of h1.h are simply embedded in the source file with the include directives, after the include directive for iostream, which itself may include stdint.h¹, the names in stdint.h are available to h1.h's code. If, where you include h2.h, you are not including stdint.h first, then you will receive errors as you claim to.

1. It is important to note that iostream is used as an example here. I have no idea if iostream actually includes stdint.h. Whether or not it does also varies between standard library implementations.

Comment: Actually till now I am just creating heades and .cpp s, they are yet to be tested, so I think this may not be the case